# I need a div box to press right against another div box

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a friend their portfolio website, and everything is simple enough, but I can't seem to get the sideways navigation to touch the content box. I've got it close, it's perhaps 50 to 75, 100 pixels at most, but they simply won't touch.

This is the code for the two div in question. I was able to twist the navigation with help from someone else's question, but they still won't sit flush. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much for your time.

```
.background {
background-image: url(textureimg.jpg);
width: 800px;
height: 1000px;
float: left;
```

}

```
 .navigation {
float: left;
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(90deg);
/* Internet Explorer */
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
```

}

Comment: Learning firebug or developer tools would benefit you greatly.  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/videos

Answer (score 1):

Probably a margin issue. Try `.navigation { margin-right: 0px; }`. Unless your navigation is on the right side, then use `margin-left`. You may also have to adjust the margin of the content section.

All of the "content" in an element takes up only a small part of that element's screen space. The rest is for *padding*, *border*, and *margin*. These can each be adjusted with CSS via `padding: 10px;`, `border: 5in;`, `margin: 3pt;` respectively (obviously you can use whatever size values you want). You can also manipulate individual sides, such as `padding-right: 10px; padding-top 5px;`

If adjusting the navigation's margin doesn't give the desired result, try adjusting the border and padding as well.

[image: HTML box model]
<sub>(source: [html.net](http://www.html.net/tutorials/css/figure008.gif))</sub>

There's a good intro to the HTML box model [here](https://html.net/tutorials/css/lesson9.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
#content { position: relative; left: -50px; }
```

adjust the left to however many pixels you need till it's not too hot or too cold, but just right